# Upload a website in IIS 7

Tags: iis, web, upload, host

Hi I have made a website by Visual Studio 2010, **but using .Net framework 3.5**.

Now I'm uploading my website to an IIS7 environment. When I do this I get the following error :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this >> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055

Answer (score 1):

The error is detailed in the "Detailed Error Information" and highlighted in the Config Source i.e.

> There is a duplicate...

So go look in the web.config and tidy up the duplicated section and you should be a bit further forward...